# Different hash in the same commits after svn synchronization

Tags: git, version-control, migration, git-svn, hashcode

So I've got really big svn repo and did migration to git and got correct repo

```
git svn clone path_to_svn
```

after I did synchronization with

```
git svn fetch
git svn rebase
```

and it worked for the first time, but on the second attempt it failed with ***unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history***, though I was on the sync branch, which wasn't changed at all, we just sync on it and then merge master with it. 
I decided to do new clone and try to set remotes on my project and merge this new branch and after cloning it I spotted that the same commits have different hash, but I'm 100% sure, that they are the same. The same diffs, authors and so on. 
**Why do I see different hash for the same commits?**

Comment: If they have different (committer or author or both) timestamps, your commits will have different hashes.

Comment: That's exactly the same commit, which was synchronized to git twice. But to different repositories.So basically git svn clone affects the counting of hash or why?

Comment: @lummycoder, I'm not a `git-svn` expert, but in the Git world if you create the "same" commit twice it will have different hashes (usually because the timestamp is different.) If you've synchronized the same Subversion commit to Git twice, that's probably what's happening.

Comment: @Chris, I understand it, but this commit was commited once in svn, so basically you don't create it again. Because it has own timestamp of creation and git should copy it, am I wrong?

Comment: `git-svn` doesn't import anything from Subversion. Rather, it creates a new commit for each revision it receives from Subversion. Two different clones, two completely different sets of commits (although the tree objects *referenced* by the different commits may be the same).

Comment: Of course git-svn creates new commit, but it's based totally on the same commit and creation time and date of commit left the same, author too and so on. That's why the history after synchronization is the same. Does hash sum counts date and time of commit creation and time of pushing? Because time of creation it takes from svn commit as I know. Or that's some other variables also? Which don't depend on svn commit?

Answer (score 2):

Usually, `git-svn` will create the same Git objects when you clone a repository again. It will use the Subversion repository’s author name and checkin date to set the commit author and committer, it will set the commit message according to the checkin message in Subversion, and it will create the content correctly. So you *should* end up with identical commit objects (I just verified that this is the case myself).

However, that only applies, if the conditions are the same for both clones. This means for example that you are specify the same branch layout, and that the server returns the proper timestamps (I could see some issue with DST changes). It’s also important that the Subversion URL is still identical since it’s being embedded in the Git commit messages.

I’d suggest you to do a `git cat-file -p <hash>` of two commits that should be identical in each clone. That way, you can try to figure out what might be the difference between the clones. You could also open `gitk` side-by-side for each repository to go through the commits and try to spot where one history might have changed.

Comment: Ok, I'll try. I know, that svn repo has new commits during next clone, but old one is exactly the same. So next clone process contains more revisions, than previous. Thank you for your answer!